# setContentView of the application

Tags: android

So I have checkbox in settings to enter the different xml
 `<CheckBoxPreference android:title="Full Screen"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="checkbox3"`
I use if checkbox3 is not checked then setContentView(1st xml) if it is checked setContentView(second xml)

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", true);
    if(samples==false)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);
    }
```

My problem is that default value of checkbox is false so when you first run application it should setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but it enters  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); even if it is "false" in settings.

Comment: where do you write the checkbox value in the SHaredPreference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", true);` to `boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", false);`

You have set the default value to `true` instead of `false`

Comment: I cant yet, i need to wait 3 minutes more ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken the default value of Check box is true according to your code:

```
boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", true);
```

Change it to

```
boolean samples = getPrefs.getBoolean("checkbox3", false);
```

And you be fine